# How would I pass my converted timestamp date from fetch api to my component?

Tags: reactjs, object, timestamp, fetch, response

I was just found some solution of converting timestamp. But in my case how would I pass the converted date to my object response JSON in the page?

Consider the code below:

```
componentDidMount(){
        const loginEmail = localStorage.getItem('loginEmail');
        this.setState({loginEmail})
        console.log(loginEmail)
         fetch(`http://localhost:9000/api/event/view/${loginEmail}`,)
         .then((resp)=>{
           resp.json().then((res)=>{
             console.log(res.data.event_info);
             this.setState({data: res.data});
            console.log("Start Date: " + new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US').format(res.data.event_info.start_date))
           })
         })

       }
```

I get the result of **Start Date: 2/19/2019** from console. But now how would I passing this start date to my component?

```
<div className="container">
   {
                  Object.keys(data).map((key) => 
                      <div className="user-detail">
                          <h1>Event Name:</h1>
                          <p> { data[key].event_name }</p>
                          <h1>Event Email:</h1>
                          <p>{ data[key].event_email }</p>
                          <h1>Event Description:</h1>
                          <p>{ data[key].event_description }</p>
                          <h1>Event Type:</h1>
                          <p>
                              { data[key].event_type }
                            </p>
                          <h1>Event Start Date:</h1>
                          <p>{ data[key].start_date }</p>
                          <h1>Event End Date:</h1>
                          <p>{ data[key].end_date }</p>
                      </div>
                  )
    }  
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Option 1: Format directly in render

Instead of `<p>{ data[key].start_date }</p>`
write   `<p>{new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US').format(data[key].start_date)}</p>`.

In the render function you can write JavaScript, so you can format the date there as you do in your `console.log`.

A cleaner approach would be to have a formatDate method in your React class component,

```
// This can even be a global helper function, it doesn't use any class variables
formatDate(timestamp) {
   return new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US').format(timestamp);
}

render() {
   ...
   <p>{ this.formatDate(data[key].start_date) }</p>
   ...
}
```

## Option 2: Save formatted date in state

You could also store the correct format in the state as soon as you get the data.
Instead of `this.setState({data: res.data})`:

```
this.setState({
   data: res.data,
   formattedStartDate: new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US').format(res.data.event_info.start_date)
});
```

And then in your render function use like `<p>{ this.state.formattedStartDate }</p>`.

Saving the formatted date in the state is more efficient because if your component is re-rendered without the state being changed, it will use the already formatted date string instead of formatting it again.

Note that if you have data for multiple events (I see you do a map over the keys in data) you should store the formatted dates for all the events. This example only considers the case when you have only one formatted date that you want to save.

## Option 3: Extract formatting logic into a React Component

This might be a bit too much for such a simple case, but you could have a component called `<FormattedDate />` which receives a timestamp as prop and renders the formatted time.

```
<div className="user-detail">
  ...
  <FormattedDate timestamp={data[key].start_date} />
  ...
</div>
```

The advantage of this approach is that you can reuse this in other parts of your application and then if you ever decide to stylize the dates in some way or change the way you format, you just have to change this one component and it will be updated everywhere.

When creating the `<FormattedDate />` component you should make it a [PureComponent](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent), so it only rerenders if the timestamp changes. This way you can safely use **Option #1** and just format the date inside the render function, and if the timestamp doesn't change there will be no useless computations being made.

Comment: Thanks!!! Its works on me....really appreciate on your guidance.

Comment: @kokoka Glad to help! Note that in React you can do something in 100 ways, and usually there is no best-way to do something. The things to look for are not adding to much logic in the render function (if it can be moved somewhere else) and avoiding duplicate code by creating more components.

Comment: Also check Option 3, as it is a more elegant and reusable way of formatting data.

Comment: but on your advise, option 2 saving data in state are most and better way right?

Comment: If you plan to show the formatted date only here, yes. If you have multiple components where you have a timestamp and want to show the formatted date I would recommend Option #3.